# What is libcontent_shell_content_view.so and how can I modify it?

Tags: javascript, android, multithreading, chromium

I am currently creating an Android app using a custom (not by me) chromium and creating a website in it. The website will be the front-end of the app, and it uses a lot of Javascript code.
I would like to implement multi-threading in the code to make the whole thing more user-friendly (better performances) and to allow some threads to freeze without having the whole website crashing.

To do that, I am using Web Workers which is a great feature. Though, there are some libraries (such as jQuery or Swipe) that use the `window` object, object that can't be accessed from a Web Worker.

I tried to customize the libraries (remove the unused `window` objects, etc) but either the worker won't load the library, or the library isn't working anymore. 
So finally I tried to modify the chromium source code to allow access to the `window` object. But I can't find reference to Web Workers anywhere, the only file containing something interesting (when I ran *grep* on the whole project) is the file `libcontent_shell_content_view.so`.

And after hours on the internet, I can't find where this library come from? What does it do? And is it possible to modify it?

Thanks,

Clems4ever

Comment: This is neat effort, but it seems like a dangerous thing to try. A JavaScript environment is generally not meant to be directly accessed by multiple threads at once, hence the Web Worker model of creating separate environments in separate threads. If you somehow got a reference to the main `window` in one of the workers, I'd expect it to lead to crashes or errors from non-thread-safe logic.

Comment: I know. But I really need these libraries to work in the web workers, and I can't do it without it. I prefer some crahses to nothing at all.